# Filter FeatureCollection with multiple values

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Is it possible to use an equality filter for a FeatureCollection in GEE based on multiple values? I understand how to filter by one value:

```
collectionName.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN','VALUE'));
```

But what if I wanted to filter by a list of values? Something like:

```
var lis = ee.List(['VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3']);
```

Is it possible to apply this to equality filter? I tried to do the following:

```
collectionName.filter(ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN',lis));
```

It ran, but didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

The `inList` filter is what you want for looking for any value in a list:

```
collectionName.filter(ee.Filter.inList('COLUMN', lis))
```

If instead you want to use several filters (so that you can use other conditions than equality, or multiple properties), you can use `ee.Filter.or`:

```
collectionName.filter(
  ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN', 'VALUE1')
    .or(ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN', 'VALUE2'))
    .or(ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN', 'VALUE3')))
```

This is the same as the first filter but can be changed to look at different properties, for example. If you already have a simple list of values, `inList` is the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Create variable containing the filter:

   var target_values  = ee.Filter.inList('COLUMN', ['VALUE1', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE3']);
2. Apply filter on the `FeatureCollection`:

   var features_select = ee.FeatureCollection("...").filter(target_values)