# Filter FeatureCollection by multiple properties

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter

I have a FeatureCollection ('results'), with several cloud probability values as properties (from different dates).

These properties are called "CLD01", "CLD02",...

I want to filter my collection in a way that only features remain which have 0 cloud probability at any given time, which means each of the "CLD" has to be 0.

I know how to filter my Feature collection by ONE of them:

```
var results_clear = results.filter(ee.Filter.eq('CLD01', 0))
```

I found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358718/filter-featurecollection-with-multiple-values) that I can filter my collection by multiple properties using this approach:

```
collectionName.filter(
  ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN', 'VALUE1')
    .or(ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN', 'VALUE2'))
    .or(ee.Filter.eq('COLUMN', 'VALUE3')))
```

but it does not work with ".and" (also not with ".or", I tried it)

This is what I did:

```
var results_clear = results.filter(ee.Filter.eq('CLD01', 0)).and(ee.Filter.eq('CLD02', 0))
```

and I get this error:

> Line 256: results.filter(...).and is not a function

I feel like this should be an easy thing to do but somehow...it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `ee.Filter.and` to filter using both properties.

```
var results_clear = results.filter(ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.eq('CLD01', 0),
                                                 ee.Filter.eq('CLD02', 0)));
```

Comment: So I was right about one thing: it actaully IS easy. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, multiple filters are all anded anyway.  So you could just do: `results.filter(ee.Filter.eq('CLD01', 0)).filter(ee.Filter.eq('CLD02', 0))` or better: `results.filter("CLD01 == 0 && CLD02 == 0")`

Comment: I also tried your method, Noel, and it worked fine for just those two properties but when I add the whole bunch of properties I want to filter on, I get an error. You might notice, I changed my operator to != (as I changed sth in the workflow) but when I try your proposed approach, it work for 2 properties (CLD01 and CLD02 but not for all of them: FeatureCollection (Error)
Collection.filter: Expression parse error at character 118:
'CLD01 != 0 && CLD02 != 0 && CLD03 != 0 .......' I checked for spelling errors and the usual suspects but it is not working for my whole list of specifications.